# Embedding Vimeo video inside a PNG image

Tags: html, image, video, vimeo

I am trying to play a certain video inside a PNG image of an iPhone. The iPhone is serving as a frame for the video. I was able to achieve this using this CSS code:

```
        #phone_container {
          width: 343px;
          /* Adjust Phone image width */
          height: 663px;
          /* Adjust Phone image height */
          position: relative;
        }

        #phone_container:after {
          content: '';
          display: block;
          background: url('iphone png link') no-repeat top left transparent;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          left: 0px;
          top: 0px;
          position: absolute;
          z-index: 10;
        }
        #video-placeholder {
          position: absolute;
          top: 125px;
          /* Adjust top position */
          left: 55px;
          /* Adjust left position */
          z-index: 5;
        }
```

I was also able to achieve this using this HTML code:

```
        <div class="row demo-video">
          <div class="col-md-5 left-side" id="phone_container">
            <div>
              <iframe id="video-placeholder" src="Video Link" width="270" height="464" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Although it is working perfectly fine, the only problem is that since the `z-index` of the `iframe` is less than the image. The Vimeo player controls are not working.  I tried setting the `z-index` of the player controls higher than that of the iPhone but it's still not working. It's also not responsive. How do I fix this problem? Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you using fixed sizes? It obviously won't be responsive. Use percentages instead.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `div` element and set its `width` and `height` attributes in CSS. Then apply the `background-image` for that div. Then you can try to embed the vimeo video within that `div`:

```
<div class="vimeo-video">
<!-- vimeo embed link with appropriate width and height //-->
</div>
```

Add CSS like this:

```
.vimeo-video {
    background-image: url('link-to-png.png');
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    padding-top: /* play around with this to fit the video */;
    padding-bottom: /* play around with this to fit the video */;
    padding-left: /* play around with this to fit the video */;
    padding-right: /* play around with this to fit the video */;
}
```

Keep `padding` values in percentages to enable a responsive design.